# Angular 4 : Refresh data in a div

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page where I am showing data DIVs in a loop after getting from a REST service which returns me a list. Each DIV is for one Inspection. After loading data when I click on one A+ or A- to increment/decrement data, I am calling another service. Now this REST call is done from another component. And the REST service returns me only one Inspection (not a list of Inspection). So after getting response from REST, I want to update the counts in that Inspection where I have clicked

Main.component.html

```
<p>Filter Data goes here</p>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" *ngFor="let inspection of inspectionList let index=index; let odd=odd; let even=even">
        <app-inspection [inspect]="inspection"></app-inspection>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http
        .get('api/inspection/1')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            let data = response.json();
            if (data.inspectionList) this.inspectionList = data.inspectionList;
        })
        .catch(error => {
        });
}
```

insp.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div> {{inspect.inspectionDescription}} </div> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a [routerLink]="" (click)="updateCount(inspect.id, 1, 'AM')" class="btn btn-success">A-</a></td>
            <td>{{inspect.rankAcount}}</td>
            <td><a [routerLink]="" (click)="updateCount(inspect.id, 1, 'AP')" class="btn btn-danger">A+</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Now onClick of A+ or A-, I am calling a POST service (**in another component.ts**) to update in database and return result.

insp.component.ts

```
updateCount() {
    this.http
        .post(url, params, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            let data = response.json();
            if (data.rankAcount) alert(data.rankAcount);
        })
        .catch(error => {
        });
}
```

Now How I will update the count only in one Inspection without reloading the entire page.

[image]
Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you won't increment rankAccount for inspection on updateCount and if POST fails you just decrement it, and for decrement action the same you will decrement on click and on fail you just increment it back.

```
incrementCount(inspect, modelId, rank) {
    inspection.rankAcount += rank;
    updateCount({
        inspectionId: inspect.id,
        modelId: modelId,
        rankChange: inspection.rankAcount
    }).then(() => {
        // etc.
    }).catch(() => {
        inspection.rankAcount -= rank;
    });
}

decrementCount(inspect, modelId, rank) {
    inspection.rankAcount -= rank;
    updateCount({
        inspectionId: inspect.id,
        modelId: modelId,
        rankChange: inspection.rankAcount
    }).then(() => {
        // etc.
    }).catch(() => {
        inspection.rankAcount += rank;
    });
}

updateCount(params) {
    this.http.post(url, params, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();
}
```

Or like this, but I would stick to 3 methods.

```
updateCount(inspection, nr) {
    inspection.rankAcount += nr;
    this.http.post(url, params, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise().then(() => {
        // etc.
    }).catch(() => {
        inspection.rankAcount -= nr;
    });
}

updateCount(inspection, 1);
updateCount(inspection, -1);
```

Comment: That is good idea. But I have some other business logics, based on that I have to increment by One or Two etc...

Comment: You are not limited by this you can add extra params 'nr' I will update.
You can have one method to it depends on you clean code rules

Comment: The other thing is, in your function it is  updateCount(inspection), But I am passing individual params, like: updateCount(inspId: number, modelId: number, rankChange: string)

Comment: My example is just based on logic how this would work, you are free to add any params that will fit your business logic ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please tell me how to pass the object (i.e. inspection) from html to component method ?

Comment: Just pass the inspect, remove ".id", I am not aware of your implementation but I suppose "ispect" is the object.

Comment: passing inspection object helped... Thanks for the suggestion.